# Proving there is an eigenvalue $\lambda$ for which $|\lambda - b_{jj}| < \epsilon \sqrt{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ real symmetric matrix. By applying Jacobi's
>   method, suppose we have generated an orthogonal matrix $R$ and a
>   symmetric matrix $B$ such that the equality
>
> $$B = R^{T}AR $$
>
> holds. Moreover, suppose the inequality $|b_{ij}| < \epsilon$ holds
>   for all $i \neq j$.
>
> Show that for each $j = 1, 2, \ldots, n$, there is at least one
>   eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ such that $|\lambda - b_{jj}| < \epsilon \sqrt{n}$ holds.

---

This is an exercise that I am doing to study for my final exam. So, I've just recently learned Jacobi's method, and I know that the eigenvalues and eigenvectors are related to the matrices $B$ and $R$; however, I have no idea how to use those results to prove an inequality. I also have no idea how to get the $\sqrt{n}$ term in there. I would greatly appreciate any help in this exercise.

Thanks

---

UPDATE: These are some theorems in my book that might help.

**Theorem (Gerschgorin’s Theorem):** Let $n \geq 2$ and $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$. All eigenvalues of $A$ lie in the region $D = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} D_{i}$, where $D_{i}$ are the Gerschgorin discs of $A$.

**Definition: (Gerschgorin Disc):** Suppose $n \geq 2$ and $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$. The Gerschgorin discs $D_{i}$ of the matrix $A$ are defined by the closed circular regions

$$D_{i} = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z - a_{ii}| \leq R_{i}\}, $$

where $$ R_{i} = \sum_{j = 1, \\ i \neq j}^{n}  |a_{ij}|$$

is the radius of $D_{i}$.

**Theorem (Bauer-Fike):** Suppose $A$ and $E$ are real symmetric $n\times n$ matrices and $B = A - E$. Assume, further, that the eigenvalues of $A$ are denoted by $\lambda_{j}, j = 1, 2, 3, \ldots, n$ and $\mu$ is an eigenvalue of $B$. Then at least one eigenvalue of $\lambda_{j}$ of $A$ satisfies $|\lambda_{j} - \mu| \leq ||E||_{2}$, where $|| \cdot ||_{2}$ denotes the $2$-norm of a matrix.

Book link: http://newdoc.nccu.edu.tw/teasyllabus/111648701013/Numerical_Analysis.pdf

The problem is from chapter 5. I would appreciate it if the answer does not use too many outside results from the book. I suppose a few are okay though, as long as they aren't really strong results that are hard to understand.

Comment: Maybe Gershgorin might apply?

Comment: @copper.hat I have no idea how to proceed. Can you please help me? I will update my original post with my the statement of Gerschgorin's Theorem

Comment: Offhand, I can only get $(n-1)\epsilon$, but **all** eigenvalues lie in $\cup_k B(b_{jj}, (n-1)\epsilon)$.

Comment: @gallileo The eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ are the same. You can easily find matrices $B$ that do not satisfy the proposed condition. So, either the result is false or coming from Jacobi's method sets some restrictions on $B$.

Comment: @PierreCarre: Can you give one of the examples please?

Comment: @copper.hat I cannot... In the example I thought of one of the eigenvalues did not satisfy the condition. However, the statement was "at least one of the eigenvalues..." so my example does not apply.

Comment: Has anyone tried this one? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72832/overlapping-gershgorin-disks

Comment: I think that Theorem $5.6$ in the text also looks similar to this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The eigenvalues of a matrix and its similarity transform are the same, so the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ are the same.

Next, for every $j=1,2,\ldots,n$, define a symmetric matrix $E^{(j)}=(B-b_{jj}I)e_je_j^T+e_je_j^T(B-b_{jj}I)$, where $e_j$ is $j^\text{th}$ standard basis vector. We have
\begin{equation}
(B-E^{(j)})e_j= Be_j - (B-b_{jj}I)e_j+e_je_j^T(B-b_{jj}I) e_j= b_{jj}e_j,
\end{equation}
since $e_je_j^TBe_j = e_j(e_j^TBe_j )= b_{jj}e_j.$
Thus, $b_{jj}$ is an eigenvalue of $B-E^{(j)}$, and hence we invoke Bauer-Fike theorem to show that there exists an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $B$ such that
\begin{equation}
\vert b_{jj}-\lambda\vert\leq \Vert E^{(j)}\Vert = \Vert(B-b_{jj}I)e_j\Vert = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1,i\neq j}^nb_{ij}^2}\leq \sqrt{n-1}\epsilon<\sqrt{n}\epsilon.
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks. What is the meaning of each $E^{(j)}$? Is it arbitrary?

Comment: Does $(B - b_{jj}I)e_{j}e_{j}^{T}$ represent the diagonal elements of matrix $B$? And the second term in $E^{(j)}$ represents the off-diagonal elements of matrix $B$? Is that correct?

Comment: $E^{(j)} $ is well defined perturbation for every $j$. It perturbs the original matrix so that the perturbed matrix has $b_{jj}$ as it's eigenvalue.

Comment: How can I see that they have the same eigenvalue?

Comment: $(B-b_{jj})e_j$ represents the $j^\text{the}$ column of $B$ with the $j$ entry replaced by 0. $E^{(j)}$ is zero everywhere except the $j^\text{the}$ row and column replaced with $(B-b_{jj})e_j$. Note that $E^{(j)}$ is different for each $j$.

Comment: Substitute for $E^{(j)}$ to show the following:\begin{equation}
(B-E^{(j)})e_j=b_{jj}e_j.
\end{equation} Then, $b_{jj}$ is the eigenvalue corresponding to the eigenvector $e_j$.

Comment: For better clarity I have edited the post!

Comment: $e_j = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \ldots & 0 & 1 & 0 \ldots & 0 \end{bmatrix}^T$. Thus, $e_je_j^Te_j = e_j(e_j^Te_j)=e_j$.

Comment: My apologies. For some strange reason I was using $(1,1,1...)^T$.

Comment: @gallileo22 Hope you are convinced. Do well for your exams!