# A stronger theorem than Gershgorin theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

> Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be a symmetric matrix in $\Bbb R^{n\times n}$, then for any $1\le i\le n$, there is an eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ such that $|a_{ii}-\lambda_i|^2\le \sum_{j\neq i}a_{ij}^2$.

I've being trying many ways to solve this problem, including induction, similar way like Gershgorin's theorem, but I failed.

Comment: To be sure that I understand well the indexation in the summation: do you mean on the RHS all the squares of entries of the i-th line excluding $a_{ii}$ ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3219637

Comment: The proof is correct with perfect construction. w_w

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution using the canonical form for symmetry matrices. We prove by contradiction. Suppose there is an $i$ such that the $>$ inequalities hold for each eigenvalue. Let $Q^TAQ=D$ which is a diagonal matrix and $Q$ is orthogonal. Then for any $||x||=1$ we have $((D-a_{ii}I)x,(D-a_{ii}I)x)>\sum_{j\neq i}a_{ij}^2$. Using the canonical form above we have $((A-a_{ii}I)x,(A-a_{ii}I)x) >\sum_{j\neq i}a_{ij}^2$. Letting $x = e_i$ leads to the contradiction.